# Prevent mounting a partition in fstab

Tags: mount, external-hdd, fstab, automount

So I feel really bad for asking this question because it looks like it has been asked a million times on the internet. I am even finding a very consistent answer, and I am not getting any errors when I try the solution I found, but it is still not working.

Here is the issue. I have an ntfs partition on an external hard drive that I do not want to mount on startup (sound like a freaking common problem or what?).

I have found this question asked all over the internet, and the single answer that comes back pretty much unanimously is I should be using the "noauto" option in fstab for the device. Even the man pages for fstab states:

"**noauto** do  not  mount  when  "mount  -a" is given (e.g., at boot time)"

Sounds like that is what I want right?! Well I am using that option and the drive is still mounted by the time I log into my account.

Here are my fstab entries for the 2 partitions that are on the same external drive:

```
#External 2TB drive
UUID=8598c4fc-171a-4324-a4d3-06145d12ceba /media/Storage   ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       2
#Windows compatability partition on external drive does not need to be mounted.
UUID=751E843A54B3D902 /media/Windows\040Compatability     ntfs    noauto     0        0
```

I am at a total loss for why the noauto option is not working like I expect it to, but when I start up my pc the drive is available and mounted at the location specified (/media/Windows Compatability). I tried changing the options (like user/nouser) and those behaved as expected. Just the **noauto** is completely baffling me.

Thanks for any help.

B.

PS: If you are curious about the use case, there is a 2TB ext4 partition on the drive, and then a small ntfs partition on it. The point of the ntfs is to carry some windows tools for reading ext4 when I have to use my drive on a strange machine.

Comment: My guess is that you are mistaken: the drive is not mounted automatically at boot time ( which is also what happens when you have *no* entry for it in fstab ).  The shell still shows the icon for it so you can mount it by clicking on it.

Comment: I think @psusi could be right. Try to issue `mount` after boot and see the results. Now, if the disk is inserted AFTER boot, now it is managed by `udisks` --- which I think does not even look at fstab, and on a "plug" event mounts everything it sees...

Comment: I believe it is mounted because the icon has the option to eject it before I ever click on the link (there is a little eject symbol over it just like all my other drives). Right clicking (without opening the drive) reveals the eject option and not the mount option.

Comment: @psusi forgot to tag (and now I cant edit it) but see above

Comment: Does it show up when you open a terminal and run `findmnt`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just comment the line in fstab to disable it on boot?

```
#UUID=751E843A54B3D902 /media/Windows\040Compatability     ntfs    noauto     0        0
```

You should still be able to mount he partition simply with nautilus whenever you need it.

Comment: That was the state of my machine before I started tinkering to solve this problem in the first place. The system automounts usb drives when there is no entry in fstab. They are mounted to /media/<username>/<drive label>

Answer (score 0):

If the disk is mounted by `udev`, try to add a file `81-hide-my-disk.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d` with the content:

```
ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="751E843A54B3D902", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}:="1"
```

(strange UUID, by the way).

By the way, i *think* you probably need to reload `udev` rules after the change:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

[Original source is on Unix-Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/preventing-mounting-some-partition-by-user-gnomeudisk).

I checked the language in the (current in 13.10) `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules` and it seems that it is still the same.

Comment: I will try this when I get home today. I am wondering how this works? Does it hide the drive from udev (so I will never be able to mount it?)? PS: I also thought it was a strange UUID. I created the partition with the same session of gparted I used to make the ext4 (and I assume gparted is what assigns the UUID on creation), so I dunno lol

Comment: Disclaimer: my experience with `udev` is relative, and sometime frustrating. I *think* it will hide it, and that you can mount it by `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sd<whatever>`. Not sure though.